# cant read correct info from a txt file

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

I have looked all over and found basically the same info, I am using :

```
for /f "skip=1" %%p IN ("%tmp%") DO (set var1=%%p)
```

but I am either not getting the second line or its not reading anything, how ever if I do

```
for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%p IN ("%tmp%") DO (set var1=%%p)
```

I will get the last line of the tmp file

The tmp file has 3 lines, the first one is useless (its an out put from a sql script) , The second line is a count, what i want, And the last row is just (1 rows affected), which i also don't want

Comment: It's because the `for /F` loop iterates over all lines (except the slipped ones), so just append `& goto :NEXT` after the `set "var1=%%p"` command, then put the label `:NEXT` into the following line; or alternatively use input redirection twice: `< "%tmp%" (set /P var1="" & set "var1=" & set /P var1="")`...

Comment: @aschipfl that worked thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you know you only want line two, then the simplest way is to forget about using a `For` loop, and instead use `Set` with standard input:

```bat
@<"InputFile.txt" (
    Set/P"line2="
    Set/P"line2=")
@Set line2&Pause
```

I added the last line, just for you to see the assigned variable value. You'll note also that I used a direct string for the input file, you can of course use a variable, but please try not to use one with the name of an existing windows variable.

Comment: I wanted to keep it as one line if possible, I went with @aschipfl solution, but thank you.